# ImageMagick convert produces empty file

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to get a grunt.js plugin to work that puts many images together into a single one and it does not work. Debugging lead me to the call to ImageMagic convert that the plugin creates to merge the images. Yesterday I was using this plugin on a linux machine without issues. 
Today I have to work on Windows and here it does not work at all, the image is blank. No error message.

The command the plugin uses is this:

```
convert -size 476x476 xc:none -strip lapras.png -geometry +1+1 -composite lapras2.png -geometry +239+1 -composite phaser.png -geometry +1+239 -composite wtf.png -geometry +239+239 -composite healthbar.png -geometry +283+239 -composite -quality 100% png32:atlas.png
```

Here is a zip that contains the images I am using and a txt file with the exact command: http://nanodesu.info/stuff/TEST.zip

Using ImageMagick 7.0.3.0 on Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I only ask here because I know seconds later I will find the solution.

Running ImageMagick 6.9.5-9 now, which works just fine. So maybe the plugin I use produces parameters for convert that only work there.

Meaning: If you happen to use grunt-sprite-packer and found this thread make sure you use the right ImageMagick version.